# PayPal: How to purchase multiple subscriptions?

Tags: paypal

I am implementing PayPal's recurring payment and it is not clear if it is possible to allow users to purchase multiple subscriptions at once. For example, I sell a monthly newsletter. Is it possible to for a company to purchase X monthly subscriptions of the newsletter for their employees? If so, can they indicate the number of subscriptions to purchase?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you cannot set up multiple recurring payments in a single flow.
However, you *can* of course set up one recurring payment for the value of all subscriptions

combined. E.g. 10*0.99 for a 9.99 recurring payment for 10 subscription of 0.99.
(Note however, that by default recurring payments can only be increased by 20% in price unless you're using Direct Payment Recurring Payments).

Comment: [PayPal's docs](https://cms.paypal.com/mx/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_WPRecurringPayments#id086513007E9__id08651J0E0QN) directly contradicts you but provides code that doesn't work. I wish the docs could be updated to reflect your correct answer.

Comment: @Mystic, I believe the issue is that you could indeed include multiple billing agreements in a SEC flow, but not for multiple recurring payments profiles.  In fact, you can specify up to 10 billing agreements in SetExpressCheckout.  These would be for use with reference transactions as opposed to recurring payments.